# parsing through and sorting datetime object python dictionary

Tags: python, string, parsing, datetime

I'm struggling with a block of code in a larger python api to determine earliest correct input.

The logic ties a correct player's id to a timecode:

```
from datetime import datetime
import operator



check = correct_player

if check in roundplayers and check in players:
        # make str()
        results [str(datetime.now())] = check
        print(results)
else:
        print('Out of player range')
```

***{'2014-01-20 16:43:40.558436': 3}***

If I don't add the ***str()*** i get results like this:

***(datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 20, 17, 23, 50, 820882), 5)***

The program works completely but i feel like comparing strings is the wrong way to do this, even though I can sort them like this:

```
sorted_result = sorted(results.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=False)
print(sorted_result)
print ( '%s' ' wins!') % players[sorted_result[0][1]]
```

What is a better way to sort these in real time as they come in?
The sorting function currently implemented returns the sorted_result as a string, but i'd prefer to leave everything in the original results dict.

Edit:

Thanks Michael and jonrsharpe for the help!

I used parts of both of your answers to streamline this pesky block.

```
while len(roundplayers) > 0:


try:
    check = input('Player ID:\n')

except NameError:
            print ('Invalid ID')
except SyntaxError:
            print ('Invalid ID')

if  check in roundplayers and check in players:
        results [time.time()] = check
        del roundplayers[check]

else:
        print('Out of player range')

if len(roundplayers) == 0:
   print ('%s wins!') % players[results[min(results)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing strings is definitely the wrong way to do this, why not keep `datetime` objects as `dict` keys? You can compare these objects to get the `min` value, so don't need to sort them as they come in:

```
results[datetime.now()] = check
```

Then you can find the winner:

```
print("{0} wins!".format(players[results[min(results)]]))
```

Where `min(results)` is the earliest time, `results[min(results)]` is the corresponding `id`, and `players[results[min(results)]]` the corresponding `player`.

Comment: `print("{} wins!".format(players[min(**sorted_result**)]))`

gives me this error:
KeyError: (datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 20, 17, 39, 6, 390508), 5)

Comment: Why are you still creating `sorted_result`? The whole point is that you don't need it; you can get the `min` key straight out of the dictionary.

Comment: My mistake. I meant:
`print("{0} wins!".format(players[min(results)]))`

Either way, the results dict looks like this without str(): `{datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 20, 17, 39, 6, 390508), 5}`
and min() won't sort it.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my answer slightly. Do you mean `results` looks like `{datetime.datetime(...): 5, ...}`? Your formatting is a 2-tuple.

Comment: `{datetime.datetime(...): 5, ...}` like you said.

Comment: `min` just gives the minimum, as you might expect. If you want the full rankings, you need something like `[player[results[t]] for t in sorted(results, reverse=True)]`. You can use `datetime.strftime` to convert `datetime` to something more readable if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `time.time()` instead of `datetime.now()`. This gives you the current timestamp as a unix timestamp float value, which is perfectly comparable and has much less overhead when comparing than the datetime objects. When you need some human readable output, you can still format it afterwards.